What is an external IDE 37 DBI pin device?
I have a couple of Paravision SX-1 expansions for the Amiga CD32 game console, and I want to use the external DB-37 pin port for storage, however, I have never seen anything that uses that connector.  What kind of devices use it?

You might want to add a bit more information, like what compuer this is about, what is a SX-1 or a DB-37 (Do you mean DC-37?) and what interface it is used for. Last but not least, what storage are you talking about? To me a SX-1 is a supercomputer while DB-37 is a small boat

DB37 connectors were (are still?) used in telecommunications  systems.  I have seen some hard drives wired to them back in the '80s but only as bit of a kludge.

@Chenmunka DB37? Sure? Got any link?

@Raffzahn, no link I'm afraid.  I may have an old manual in the attic.  If I get a moment over the weekend...

The external connector is a non-standard reduced pin count IDE connector. I'm not aware of any commercially released accessories to connect to it but you could make a custom cable to attach up to two external IDE devices. DMA does not appear to be supported.
The pin-out can be found on pinouts.ru and is reproduced below.

37 pin D-SUB female connector
(at the controller)



Pin
Name
Description




1
/IDE-RESET
Drive Reset


2
D0
Data bit 0


3
D2
Data bit 2


4
D4
Data bit 4


5
D6
Data bit 6


6
GND
Ground


7
D8
Data bit 8


8
D10
Data bit 10


9
D12
Data bit 12


10
D14
Data bit 14


11
GND
Ground


12
GND
Ground


13
GND
Ground


14
GND
Ground


15
GND
Ground


16
GND
Ground


17
GND
Ground


18
+5V
5V Power


19
+5V
5V Power


20
GND
Ground


21
D1
Data bit 1


22
D3
Data bit 3


23
D5
Data bit 5


24
D7
Data bit 7


25
GND
Ground


26
D9
Data bit 9


27
D11
Data bit 11


28
D13
Data bit 13


29
D15
Data bit 15


30
/IOW
I/O Write


31
/IOR
I/O Read


32
IDE-IRQ
Interrupt Request


33
IDE-A2
Address bit 2


34
IDE-A1
Address bit 1


35
IDE-A0
Address bit 0


36
/BICS1
Chip Select 1


37
/BICS0
Chip Select 0




Sounds like a DC-37 to me, right?

@Raffzahn Correct, but since certain people like to argue about the nomenclature for these connectors I just kept the original generic "d-sub" wording + pin count from the linked page.

Likely nothing. The 37-pin port of the SX-1 expansion for the Amiga CD32 seems to be entirely proprietary. The port was intended to connect external IDE hard drives (in addition to the internal one, which uses an IDC connector), but IDE connectors have either 44 or 40-pin IDC connectors, never D-Sub.
You'll likely have to make your own cable if you want to use this connector.
